# Google auth2 clojurescript externs

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-compiler, google-authentication

So, I've managed to get google sign-in to work in my development cljs build by including https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js in my index.html and simply using javascript interop to emulate the instructions given here for an ordinary javascript client:  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.  However I can't get a production build with :optimizations :advanced to work.

In all my code that interacts with the gapi.auth2 object, I've used `(aget object "propertyName")` which seems to get me as far as calling calling the cljs equivalent of `gapi.load("auth2")` all the way to accessing the 'listen' function on  `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser`.

When I try to call this 'listen' function, I get a "cannot read property 'add' of undefined" error.  I don't know what object this 'add' property is supposed to exist on, if I need to create an extern for this object, or how to do so.

Am I approaching gapi.auth2 integration in a sane way in the first place?

Comment: I've resolved it by simply moving interaction with the auth2 library into a separate js file, and passing a a cljs callback into this file on the window object.  I'm not thrilled with it but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a small custom google sign-in with https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js.

Here is what I need for my `externs.js` file.

```
var gapi = {};
gapi.load = function (){};
gapi.auth2 = {};
gapi.auth2.init = function(){};
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance = function (){};
```

Basically, there's a global js object `gapi` and based on the sample codes on that google website, gapi has method `load` and attribute `auth2`. Object referenced by `gapi.auth` has `init` and `getAuthInstance` methods.

I don't recommend using `aget` to get a object's property. `aget` is meant to be used on js array. For JavaScript objects, use `goog.object/get` or the multi-arity `goog.object/getValueByKeys`.

For object whose type I don't know like your `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser`, I call the `listen` on it using `js-invoke` function.

```
 (let [callback-fn (fn [_] ...)
       auth-inst  (.getAuthInstance js/gapi.auth2)
       currentUser (goog.object/get auth-inst "currentUser")]
  (js-invoke currentUser "listen" callback-fn))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer gave me a bunch of errors/warnings when using closure compiler in advanced mode, so this is what my `google-platform.js` extern file looks like

```
/**
 * @fileoverview Externs for Google platform
 *
 * @externs
 */

/**
 * @constructor
 * @return {!gapi}
 */
function gapi() {}

/**
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {Function} success
 */
gapi.load = function (name, success) {};
gapi.prototype.load = gapi.load;

/**
 * @constructor
 * @return {!gapi.auth2}
 */
gapi.auth2 = function () {};
gapi.prototype.auth2 = gapi.auth2;

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {Object<string,*>} options
 * @return {!gapi.auth2.init}
 */
gapi.auth2.init = function (options) {};
gapi.auth2.prototype.init = gapi.auth2.init;

/**
 * @param {Element} element
 * @param {Object} options
 * @param {Function} success
 * @param {Function} error
 */
gapi.auth2.init.attachClickHandler = function (element, options, success, error) {};
gapi.auth2.init.prototype.attachClickHandler = gapi.auth2.init.attachClickHandler;

/**
 * @constructor
 * @return {!googleUser}
 */
function googleUser() {}

/**
 * @constructor
 * @return {!googleUser.getAuthResponse}
 */
googleUser.getAuthResponse = function () {};
googleUser.prototype.getAuthResponse = googleUser.getAuthResponse;

 /** @type {string} */
googleUser.getAuthResponse.id_token;
googleUser.getAuthResponse.prototype.id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse.id_token;
```

And this is the code that calls it (for a custom button)

```
let /** !gapi.auth2.init */ auth2;
gapi.load('auth2', function () {
    // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
        // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
        //scope: 'additional_scope'
});

$main.find('<selector for your button(s)>').each(/** @this {Element} */ function () {
    const t = this;
    auth2.attachClickHandler(t, {},
        function (/** Object<string,*> */ googleUser) {
            console.log(typeof googleUser, googleUser);
        },
        function (/** Object<string,*> */ error) {
            console.log(typeof error, error);
            alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
    });
});
```